# MFMessageComposeViewController , MFMailComposeViewController and SLComposeViewController keeps crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, slcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I got a lot of crash reports on my current app using the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)prepareFrameworks
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        (void)[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        (void)[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
        (void)[[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
}
```

I'm running the code to reduce the load time of the ComposeViewController on activation.

One of the stacktraces:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xe15f851f

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3ab570ec objc_retain + 11
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x3b07fd97 _Block_object_assign + 386
2  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x3b07f9e9 _Block_copy_internal + 444
3  UIKit                          0x3346f987 +[_UIAsyncInvocation invocationWithBlock:] + 74
4  UIKit                          0x33457b87 +[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest requestViewController:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:serializedAppearanceCustomizations:legacyAppearance:useXPCObjects:exportedHostingObject:serviceViewControllerDeputyInterface:connectionHandler:] + 914
5  UIKit                          0x3345a129 +[_UIRemoteViewController requestViewController:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:connectionHandler:] + 468
6  MessageUI                      0x31f0d37f +[MFMailComposeRemoteViewController requestViewControllerWithConnectionHandler:] + 62
7  MessageUI                      0x31f0a79f -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController initWithNibName:bundle:] + 126
8  MessageUI                      0x31ef2281 -[MFMailComposeViewController initWithURL:] + 216
9  MY APP                         0x000cb881 -[AppDelegate prepareFrameworks] (AppDelegate.m:262)
10 MY APP                         0x000cad61 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:128)
11 UIKit                          0x32fae2ff -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 274
12 UIKit                          0x32fadd4f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1390
13 UIKit                          0x32fa8353 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 714
14 UIKit                          0x32f4341f -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3130
15 UIKit                          0x32f42721 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
16 UIKit                          0x32fa7b3d _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 664
17 GraphicsServices               0x353de70d _PurpleEventCallback + 608
18 GraphicsServices               0x353de2f7 PurpleEventCallback + 34
19 CoreFoundation                 0x307959df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
20 CoreFoundation                 0x3079597b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
21 CoreFoundation                 0x3079414f __CFRunLoopRun + 1398
22 CoreFoundation                 0x306fec27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
23 CoreFoundation                 0x306fea0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
24 UIKit                          0x32fa6dd9 -[UIApplication _run] + 760
25 UIKit                          0x32fa2049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
26 MY APP                         0x000cac27 main (main.m:16)
```

Comment: Add the full exception type name and message.

Comment: may be it cause setting of some UIAppearance values

Comment: use zombie find exact error

Comment: i can't reproduce the error on debug builds :/

Comment: i am not using any kind of UIAppearance values in the app :/